# Paypal IPN Listener for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

There is quite a few code samples on [PayPal GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) showing how to implement IPN listener in various languages (php, VB, ...). However, there is none for the ASP.NET MVC. Has anybody successfully implemented it? Or is there, similarly to the other code samples, a preferred/oficial way of implementing it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A neat video on a simple MVC site structure that includes PayPal IPN:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-22-restructuring-rerouting-and-paypal

Direct link to his IPN controller
https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Kona.Web/Controllers/PayPalController.cs

MVC/C# Example:
http://www.markstraley.com/Code/PayPalIPN

Thanks @Earlee!

Comment: There's a lot of HttpContext reliance there. Anyone seen anything more testable?

Comment: The first link is 404 now

Comment: @gyosifov thanks for the notification. I found the original video that was the meat of the article. I replaced the link.

Comment: I also find this to be concise: http://www.markstraley.com/Code/PayPalIPN

Comment: @Earlee, good suggestion! I added the link to the answer.