# PayPal IPN with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal-ipn

I cannot seem to get any specific code with regards to IPN listeners and post backs with MVC3.

Please can someone provide me with the code for this. Struggling now for weeks, to get it.

I have managed to get the normal redirecting to Sandbox, but just the IPN stuff i need.

Can anyone assist me.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447468/paypal-ipn-listener-for-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though there is a lot of code available, check this article [Paypal IPN Listener for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447468/paypal-ipn-listener-for-asp-net-mvc)

Which links to this http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/10/11/mvcstore-part-22

Which also links to this https://mvcsamples.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Kona.Web/Controllers/PayPalController.cs

**I also recommend reading this http://www.superstarcoders.com/blogs/posts/paypal-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx**

And, this http://www.xdevsoftware.com/PPIPNDesc.aspx

And, this http://www.arunrana.net/2012/01/paypal-integration-in-mvc3-and-razor.html